# Alacritty Config File Color Changes

Tags: terminal, colors, yaml, config, alacritty

Does anyone Have any clue about what changes I have to make in the alacritty.yml file to change these colors and make it more visible!?

[image]

I tried Messing around with the config file but it was of no use as I didn't know about the necessary changes to be made!